# cefsharp - "Links that open a specific application" seem to be not working

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I just begin with Cefsharp on C#.

Everything works fine except Cefsharp can not execute some special links that open/run a specific application on the computer.

The link still works on other Chromium official browsers (Google Chrome), I clicked the link and it launches the application. Cefshap is not, it does nothing when I clicked the link.

The link looks something like this: "runapp://api.abcxyz/..."

How can I make it work on Cefsharp?

[image show that the link works on other chromium browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BerFs.png)

Comment: I think you have to create your own request handler using this interface https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.cs#L156 and according to pointers provided by CefSharp author here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly for security reasons loading of external protocols is disabled by default. Historically you would have implemented `OnProtocolExecution`.
There is currently an `upstream` bug in `OnProtocolExecution` see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2715/onprotocolexecution-page-goes-blank-after

You can implement a workaround using [RequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowser](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm) and calling `Process.Start`

It would look roughly something like the following (Written in Notepad++ very quickly, there maybe minor mistakes that you'd have to correct).

```cs
public class ExampleRequestHandler : RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        if(request.Url.StartsWith("mailto:"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(request.Url);
            //Cancel navigation
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

browser.RequestHandler = new ExampleRequestHandler();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solve my problem and work perfectly!
All I have to do is just replace the Url start with my link start path!
Thank you very much, I am very appreciated!